# using cUrl to read feed on same domain

Tags: php, wordpress, curl, xml-parsing, subdomain

I am not sure if this is the problem. i am using cUrl to read a wordpress feed. This works ok now.

I tried it with several wordpress feeds. but I can't get it working with a worpress feed on the same domain

So I want to present the feed from http://www.digins.nl/blog results on http://www.digins.nl.

here is the code I use:

```
$wpsite = $wpsite.'/feed';
   $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $wpsite);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 15);
  $returned = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);

  // $xml === False on failure
  $xml = simplexml_load_string($returned, 'SimpleXMLElement', LIBXML_NOCDATA);
```

Is it right that it do not work on the same domain or is there something wrong with my code?

With the curl_error I got a 'string(24) "couldn't connect to host"' message. If I check the feed via my browser it seems to work ok.

Comment: Can you show what `$wpsit=` was in the first place before adding '/feed'?

Comment: You might be timing out. Is 15 seconds enough?

Comment: Also, check for a curl error: `curl_error($ch)`

Comment: Tried a longer timeout period, no results. $wpsite = http://www.digins.nl/blog/feed. I checked it and seems ok. How to check the curl_error?

Comment: With the curl_error I got a 'string(24) "couldn't connect to host"' message. If I check the feed via my browser it seems to work ok.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using curl? You can load the xml data easily using [file_get_contents()](http://php.net/file_get_contents) function.

Try this:

```
<pre>
<?php

$xml = simplexml_load_string(
    file_get_contents('/blog/feed/'),
    'SimpleXMLElement',
    LIBXML_NOCDATA
);

print_r($xml);

?>
```

**EDIT :** Here's an alternate way using CURL (confirmed working)

```
<?php

// CURL HTTP Get Helper Function
function CurlGet($fromUrl)
{
    // create curl resource
    $ch = curl_init();

    // set url
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $fromUrl);

    //return the transfer as a string
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    // $output contains the output string
    $output = curl_exec($ch);

    // close curl resource to free up system resources
    curl_close($ch);

    // Return Output
    return (!empty($output) ? $output : false);
}   

// Get XML Data From RSS Feed
$xml_str = CurlGet('http://www.digins.nl/blog/feed/');

// Check If We Have Data
if ($xml_str)
{
    // Load XML
    $xml = simplexml_load_string($xml_str, 'SimpleXMLElement', LIBXML_NOCDATA);

    // Debug
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($xml);
    echo '</pre>';
}
else
{
    // Curl request failed
}

?>
```

---

This is the output I got when I tested it:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [@attributes] => Array
        (
            [version] => 2.0
        )

    [channel] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [title] => Digins news
            [link] => http://www.digins.nl/blog
            [description] => Just another WordPress site
            [lastBuildDate] => Thu, 31 Oct 2013 10:24:25 +0000
            [language] => en-US
            [generator] => http://wordpress.org/?v=3.7.1
            [item] => Array
                (
                    [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [title] => test3
                            [link] => http://www.digins.nl/blog/test3/
                            [comments] => http://www.digins.nl/blog/test3/#comments
                            [pubDate] => Thu, 31 Oct 2013 10:24:25 +0000
                            [category] => Uncategorized
                            [guid] => http://www.digins.nl/blog/?p=9
                            [description] => 3e bericht
                        )

                    [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [title] => hello world 2
                            [link] => http://www.digins.nl/blog/hello-world-2/
                            [comments] => http://www.digins.nl/blog/hello-world-2/#comments
                            [pubDate] => Thu, 31 Oct 2013 10:07:35 +0000
                            [category] => Uncategorized
                            [guid] => http://www.digins.nl/blog/?p=5
                            [description] => Dit is een test bericht
                        )

                    [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [title] => Hello world!
                            [link] => http://www.digins.nl/blog/hello-world/
                            [comments] => http://www.digins.nl/blog/hello-world/#comments
                            [pubDate] => Wed, 25 Sep 2013 21:25:08 +0000
                            [category] => Uncategorized
                            [guid] => http://www.digins.nl/blog/?p=1
                            [description] => Welcome to WordPress. This is your first post. Edit or delete it, then start blogging!
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

---

If my updated CURL method does not work, then there is an issue with your hosting provider... check with them, because it works fine when I run it from dev PC.

Comment: I am using curl because fopen is disabled on my hosting. with curl it works on other xml feeds.

Comment: have you tried my example? It's using standard http get to make a request the the target web page and grabing the output (xml) into the xml parser. You don't need `curl` or `fopen`.

Comment: I tried, received an arror:
Warning: file_get_contents() [function.file-get-contents]: http:// wrapper is disabled in the server configuration by allow_url_fopen=0 in /home/vhosts/digins.nl/httpdocs/noname2.php on line 4

Warning: file_get_contents(http://www.digins.nl/blog/feed/) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: no suitable wrapper could be found in /home/vhosts/digins.nl/httpdocs/noname2.php on line 4

Comment: Wait... I've just realised it's on the same domain... i've updated my code, try that.

Comment: the fopen error is gone indeed. but there is still the second one: Warning: file_get_contents(/blog/feed/) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/vhosts/digins.nl/httpdocs/noname2.php on line 4.

Comment: Thanks for your update. I see it works when Iuse this on a different domain. but still not working on the root of my website. It's getting frustrated...

Answer (score 0):

The problem remains that it is not possible to read a feed from the same domain. So at this moment I read the feed via feedburner. Unfortunatly it slow things down.